# TRegEx Replace Pattern?

Tags: regex, delphi, replace, delphi-xe2

I have a json data

```
  "myObject": {
      "field1": 1,
      "field2": true,
      "fileURL": [ "" ]
   }
```

How to replace into "fileURL":["here url"] ?

```
var
 pattern:string;
begin
 pattern:='"fileURL":[ "?" ]';
 Memo1.Text:=TRegEx.Replace(Trim(Memo1.Text),pattern,'C:\file1.doc');
end;
```

Comment: I'm not expert on regex, but you might try to fiddle [`this pattern`](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?34ct9). Or just use a JSON parser.

Comment: Using JSON without a parser is like buying a car and pushing to your destination

Answer (score 0):

replace your question mark with [a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+
and dont forgot backslash \ for all chars that you want exact repeat
& you should parentheses () for group founding and in replace part you can use it.

```
var
 pattern:string;
begin
 pattern:='(\"fileURL\"\:\[\s\")([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]+)(\"\s\])';
 Memo1.Text:=TRegEx.Replace(Trim(Memo1.Text),pattern,'$1C:\file1.doc$3');
end;
```

Comment: thank you but does not work :(
Here is Test project 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/haj29dhtsga50h7/SampleProject.rar

Comment: It looks like there are too many escaped characters in this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the whole line.

```
pattern := '"fileURL"\s*:\s*\[\s*"[^"]*"\s*\]';
fileName := 'C:\file1.doc';
Memo1.Text := TRegEx.Replace(Memo1.Text, pattern, '"fileURL" : ["' + fileName + '"]');
```